# ember hasMany and plurals

Tags: ember.js

```
Lost.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('countries',{path: '/'}, function(){
     this.resource('country',{path: ':country_id'},function(){
      this.resource('city',{path: ':city_id'});
    });
  });
});
```

My country model is

```
  Lost.Country = DS.Model.extend({
      countryCode: DS.attr('string'),
      countryName: DS.attr('string'),
      places: DS.hasMany('place')
    });
```

and my place model is

```
Lost.Place = DS.Model.extend({
  cityName: DS.attr('string'),  
  country: DS.belongsTo('country')
});
```

In country model when I change **places** to place this work fine 
but when i keep it as places I get error

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'store' of undefined

DEBUG: Ember      : 1.6.0-beta.1+canary.3bcd9bdc 
DEBUG: Ember Data : 1.0.0-beta.7+canary.d5562867 
DEBUG: Handlebars : 1.3.0 
DEBUG: jQuery     : 1.11.0
```

**UPDATED**

The object returned from rails server

Acual JSON:

```
{
   "countries":[
      {
         "id":1,
         "countryCode":"BH",
         "countryName":"Bhutan",
         "places":[
            {
               "id":1,
               "country_id":1,
               "cityName":"Daga"
            },
            {
               "id":2,
               "country_id":1,
               "cityName":"Ha"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Here is how my rails serializers looks

application_serializer.rb

```
class ApplicationSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  embed :ids, :include => true
end
```

country_serializer.rb

```
class CountrySerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :countryCode, :countryName
  has_many :places
end
```

place_serializer

```
class PlaceSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :country_id, :cityName
  #belongs_to :country #commented out because gives error"undefine method belongs_to"
                       #if i change it to has_one gives error"stack level too deep"
end
```

*** **Additon to anwer*** **
this question has been answered by @kingpin2k
as a part of answer if you are new developer like me instead of writing your own normalizeAttribute function I think it will be better to use already exsisting normalizeAtrribute function in DS.RESTAdapter present in ember-data. less error prone.
Just copy pasting it worked for me

> Ember Data : 1.0.0-beta.6

Comment: will you add the actual json returned, that may help identify the issue.

Comment: added the actual json.I referred to emberjs docs again and It shows hasMany key should be in plural i.e "places" in my case. and the slides I am refering to learn says sideloading is done by default. I am not able to achieve both.    slide#12 of https://speakerd.s3.amazonaws.com/presentations/dab97a705a8f013017df1231381d81f2/Optimizing_an_API_for_Ember_Data.pdf

Comment: Can you show the client side adapter you're using?  `App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend();`

Comment: `places` should match whatever the key name is on the model definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Lost.Place = DS.Model.extend({
  cityName: DS.attr('string'),  
  country: DS.belongsTo('Country')
});
```

should be (lower case country)

```
Lost.Place = DS.Model.extend({
  cityName: DS.attr('string'),  
  country: DS.belongsTo('country')
});
```

and I can't tell from your question, but the json should be an array of ids for place.

If you're using the `ActiveModelSerializer` then you can set the embedded to always, which is how you're trying to return it.  You're data is causing some hiccups, in that it sees `countryCode` as `country_code`, but you can override some functions to fix up this validation, or you can fix up your json to match the expected data.

```
App.ApplicationAdapter= DS.ActiveModelAdapter;

App.ApplicationSerializer = DS.ActiveModelSerializer.extend(DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin, {
  attrs: {
    places: {embedded: 'always'}
  },
  normalizeAttributes: function(type, hash) {
   //your attributes shouldn't be normalized
  }
});

Lost.Country = DS.Model.extend({
  countryCode: DS.attr('string'),
  countryName: DS.attr('string'),
  places: DS.hasMany('place')
});
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/342/edit

Comment: Hi ..changing it to "country" from "Country" did not help. I have updated more information.